# OpenAPI vs JSON:API

Tags: api, rest, openapi, json-api

I couldn't find any resources on the use case differences between [JSON:API](https://jsonapi.org) & [OpenAPI](https://www.openapis.org/)

From my understanding, JSON:API is more focused on the business data while OpenAPI is more about REST itself?

Any pointers would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use OpenAPI to describe API's, and JSON:API is a standard to structure your apis. If you use JSON:API, you can still use OpenAPI to describe it.

So OpenAPI's goal is really to provide a full description on how your API can be called, and what operations are available. JSON:API gives you a strong opinion on how to structure it.

Answer (score 9):

Think about it as `OpenAPI` is a “Data Format” and `JSON API` is a “Data Contract”.

More on this here: https://apisyouwonthate.com/blog/json-api-openapi-and-json-schema-working-in-harmony

Comment: working link: https://apisyouwonthate.com/blog/json-api-openapi-and-json-schema